# How to stop useFrame afrer n seconds in react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, animation, 3d, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

hi I have animation in useFrame which plays after click and I need to stop it after 2 seconds for example

```
  const [clicked, click] = useState(false)
  useFrame((state, delta) => (clicked ? group.current.rotation.x += 0.01 : 
  group.current.rotation.x))
```

any advice? , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work using the use-timer library ([use-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-timer))

Use the useTimer hook:

```
  const { time, start, pause, reset, status } = useTimer();
```

Inside the useFrame, you decide when to rotate the cube:

```
useFrame(() => {
 if (status === "RUNNING") {
  boxRef.current.rotation.x += 0.05;
 }

 if (status === "RUNNING" && time >= 2) {
  pause();
  reset();
 }
})
```

Clicking on the box starts the timer:

```
const handleClick = () => {
if (status === "PAUSED" || status === "STOPPED") {
  start();
}};
```

I am pretty sure you can do something with the state inside useFrame aswell, but that felt more complicated. (`state.clock.elapsedTime`)